# Why one of the features is dominating all rest of the features in my trained SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have been given a task to train the SVM model on [conll2003 dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/conll2003) for Named Entity "Identification" (That is I have to tag all tokens in "Statue of Liberty" as named entities not as a place, which is the case in named entity recognition.)

> Blockquote

Initially, I built a feature `first_letter_caps` which returned `1` if the first letter of the token was capital else `0`. This resulted in the first token of every sentence always getting identified as a named entity. So, I changed it to do that only for non-sentence-start-token and always return `0` for sentence-start-token (that is first word in the sentence). This resulted in the first token of every sentence always getting identified as a NON-named entity. So I realized that somehow I have to "turn off" this feature for sentence-start-token and not return a fixed value. So, I made this feature return logical OR of other features (explained in next paragraph) for sentence-start-token, thinking that this will have the effect of turning off this feature and this turned out to be true. And this was quite successful. It stopped "always" identifying sentence-start-token as either named entity or non-named-entity.

But now, I have a few issues. But let me explain other features first. But let me explain other features first. To avoid "The" in "The Federal Bank" getting identified as a named entity, I built feature `is_stopword` which returns `1` when the token is stopword else return `0`. Also, I have a third feature `contains_number` which returns `1` if the token contained number in it, else returns `0`.

I have trained `sklearn.svm.SVC` with linear kernel. But it never identified tokens containing numbers as named entities. And if stop words had first letter capital (like in "The"), it will classify it as named entity. After outputting [`SVC.coef_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.coef_) I realized that the issue is that it assigns positive coefficient only to feature `first_letter_caps` and negative or zero coefficient to all other features. When I plotted feature comparison, I realized that it is using only `first_letter_caps` feature for decision making:
[image]

Somehow the feature `first_letter_caps` is dominating all other features and SVM decision boundary. How do I fix this? What I am missing?

Comment: I suggest asking this question in another Stack Exchange community, like Data Science or Cross Validated, since this seems to be related more to the rationale behind model building and not to the code used to do it.

Comment: This may be due to the fact that you're using a linear kernel. Here's a thought experiment. Looking at the classification visualization you posted, what if a term is true if the term `contains_number` and has `first_letter_capital` (e.g. area around top left corner and bottom right corner should be true, otherwise false). No matter how you try to split this with a linear plane, it's impossible. Take a look at the [XOR problem](https://dev.to/jbahire/demystifying-the-xor-problem-1blk).

Comment: I guess the problem was data itself. Only < 1% of tokens containing numbers were classified as named entities in the training set. Most of the tokens containing numbers were tagged as non named entities. Is that why SVM was not learning anything from this feature?